# Android using Fragments and Persistence

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

i really need help. I have trouble by using Fragments. I have to solve this Problem:

[image: Problem]

I have the MiddleWare and the MainActivity with the DB. I have troubles by using the Fragments. The MainActivity should show a list of Strings, when i click on one, for example on SubFragment1, the SubFragment1 should be replace the List of Strings on the MainActivity. At the same time, the user interface of the SubFragment1 should be filled by the actual data of the DB. For example i have a textview and a button on the SubFragment1, the Textview should now contain the actual data of the DB.

Thx a lot :)

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I used the Eclipse-Example for Fragments, so i have a "ItemListActivity" which represents the Main Activity. And when i click on a Item, it starts the "ItemDetailActivity" which care about the UI of the Fragments and the "ItemListActivity" is stopped. But the "ItemListActivity" should NEVER STOP, it gets permanent Data from the MiddleWare and should update the Data in the Fragments